# cmd: ftp server -- NLST for regular files is unsupported

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, ftp

If I want to get multiple files with `mget`, then the error `NLST for regular files is unsupported` appears for every file. Downloading it with single `get` for each, then no problem. Can someone explain me the error and how to fix it?